# Sorting based on difference of the two arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am having an array of arrays, where sorting needs to happen based on the difference of the element value.

The following is the sorting method that I have used:

```
let arr = [[20, 60], [10, 30], [40, 200], [90, 300]];
let res = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - a[0] > b[1] - b[0];
});
```

The expected output should be

```
[[90,300], [40,200], [20,60], [10,30]]
//difference between elements are 210,160,40 and 20
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Notes: 1. `sort` does sort in-place (side effect on `arr`) and 2. the function should return -1, 0, or 1 [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the delta of the deltas instead of returning a boolean value.

[`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) sorts *in situ*.

```js
let array = [[20, 60], [10, 30], [40, 200], [90, 300]];

array.sort((a, b) => (b[1] - b[0]) - (a[1] - a[0]));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: What is **situ**?

Comment: it is [in place](https://www.google.de/search?q=in+situ&ie=UTF-8&oe=).

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [[20, 60], [10, 30], [40, 200], [90, 300]];
let ans = arr.sort((a, b) => {
 return (Math.abs(b[0] - b[1])) - (Math.abs(a[0] - a[1]));
});
console.log(ans);
```